# How to get my kinect hoverbutton to work on my child window

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect

I'm writing an kinect application which requires me to use the hand and act as mouse, which i have done which is called hoverbutton.
Is there any way i could get the Hoverbutton from my main window to work on my child window as well?

```
    <Window x:Class="KinectButton.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:Coding4Fun.Kinect.Wpf.Controls;assembly=Coding4Fun.Kinect.Wpf"
    Title="MainWindow" Background="#FFAD4747"
    WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize"  
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" Height="927" Width="1350">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Canvas>
    <Canvas.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="file:///C:/Users/103159T/Downloads/STORYBOARD/Background.png" />
    </Canvas.Background>
    <Controls:HoverButton Margin="0" Padding="0" x:Name="kinectButton" ImageSize="50"                                           
                            ImageSource="/Images/RightHand.png"  
                            ActiveImageSource="/Images/RightHand.png" 
                            TimeInterval="2000"  Panel.ZIndex="1000" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" />
        <Button x:Name="button1" Content="START" Height="152" Canvas.Left="594" Canvas.Top="502"  Width="320" FontSize="40" Click="button1_Click" BorderThickness="4" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" OpacityMask="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Button.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF0000C8" Offset="0.358" />
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <Label Canvas.Left="384" Canvas.Top="632" Content="" Height="66" Name="message" Width="530" Foreground="White" FontSize="40" />
        <Button Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="974" Content="Quit" Height="91" Name="quitButton" Width="137" FontSize="28" Background="#FFFF3838" Foreground="White" Click="quitButton_Click" />
        <Image Height="206" Name="videoStream" Stretch="Fill" Width="363" Canvas.Left="1002" Canvas.Top="682" />
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

that was my main window xaml which includes a button called "START" which directs me to another xaml window when clicked..

Comment: " Is there any way i could get the Hoverbutton from my main window to work on my child window as well?" what do you mean?

Comment: in the main window my hover button which is an image of a hand acts a mouse, but when i press the start button in my main window which directs to my child window, it disappears.

Comment: You put the Panel.ZIndex to 1000, but that just pushes it to the top of this particular visual tree. A child window will cover that. You need to put it on a separate topmost window to keep it in view permanently.

Comment: and how do i do that?